# Turning ethernet on and off on android

Tags: android, networking, ethernet

Is there a way to turn ethernet on and off programatically, similarly to how WiFi can be turned on and off through the `WiFiManager` class? I believe ifconfig down/up will not work as it would require root. I treid doing `ifconfig wlan0 down` in a terminal emulator, which gave me permission denied.

I'm on a non-rooted device.

Answer (score 0):

firstly, you should know, since android Q, `WifiManager` class is not worked.

> This method was deprecated in API level 29.
>   Starting with Build.VERSION_CODES#Q, applications are not allowed to enable/disable Wi-Fi. Compatibility Note: For applications targeting Build.VERSION_CODES.Q or above, this API will always return false and will have no effect. If apps are targeting an older SDK ( Build.VERSION_CODES.P or below), they can continue to use this API.

Both for the network and wifi, I suggest you show a permission dialog, let the user open it, it matches the android permission manager.

you can use the following code to  open the setting

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings",
                "com.android.settings.Settings$DataUsageSummaryActivity"));
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
```

if the target SDK below Q, you can try to use the reflect way.

```
private void setMobileDataEnabled(Context context, boolean enabled) throws Exception{
    final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    Class conmanClass = null;
    try {
        conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    final Field iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
    iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
    final Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(conman);
    final Class iConnectivityManagerClass = Class.forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
    final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
    setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);
    setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, enabled);
}
```

Comment: I'm looking to progrmatically cycle ethernet off and on without user intervention. Also, I was using the Wifi Manager as an example of an API of being able to programatically enable / disable network comms.

I'm not sure what the dialog you're suggesting would do.

Comment: for SDK above 9, those methods are not worked. see the comment

Comment: @StealthRabbi, I give a reflection way to realize it, you can try it if it still worked

Comment: i do'nt think enabling mobile data has the same effect as enabling / disabling ethernet.